# Modern C++ with lots of templates

Tags: c++, templates

I can not get used to new style of C++. Most of the STL and Boost libraries are composed of some messy templates, typedefs and enums. The only way templates make sense for me is their use in container classes. Except for that, i am not able to understand why it is widely used.

If i go a little deeper, i can guess that they are there in order to implement compile time computations and decision makings. But, it is really necessary ? If this is not the case, what is the real reason ?

(Please do not give factorial computation example for meta-programming)

Comment: Why not try a different language, like Java or Python?

Comment: Because i'm comfortable in C++ without templates :)

Comment: That statement by itself says it all :-S

Comment: the reason why templates are popular is becourse it speeds up the code and uses less memory

Comment: C++ has moved to doing a lot of work at compile time. There's runtime efficiency, but also the notion that compile-time errors are better than runtime errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just compile time computations. Type safety is *really* nice, and not something you can get at runtime. The heavy usage of templates allows for code to work with many different data types while still being statically typed and ensuring type safety. That's a huge win, in my book.

And to add another thing, templates allow different code paths to be executed based on the template parameters. For example, I just wrote a function that adds two images together, combining them into one image. Pixel values overflowing doesn't make much sense, so it uses [saturation arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic). But the pixels in the images can be represented as unsigned integers (in the range `[0, std::numeric_limits<std::uint*_t>::max()]`) or floating point numbers (in the range `[0, 1]`). The saturation logic is different depending on the data type. So I used templates and template specialization to allow different saturation logic to be executed depending on the types of the pixels. Stuff like this is done *all the time* with templates.

Answer (score 2):

Templates are not new.

Yes, they are used for the two items you mentioned. For performance, instead of run-time branches, and for managing code complexity.

Additionally, templates enable enable extending libraries for arbitrary types. Consider how a `vector<>` can contain almost anything without us actually writing that support into the vector. Templates are modular.